# Java Applet: Playing Music Fails

Tags: java, audio, applet, awt

I would like to play spacemusic.au in my applet. The music file is located in both Game/src and Game/bin.
However, it does not play the music when I click "play in loop". Since it is .au file, it should be good to play. What would be causing this?

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class playMusic extends Applet 
implements ActionListener{
   Button play,stop;
   AudioClip audioClip;
   public void init(){
      play = new Button("  Play in Loop  ");
      add(play);
      play.addActionListener(this);
      stop = new Button("  Stop  ");
      add(stop);
      stop.addActionListener(this);
      audioClip = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "spacemusic.au");
   }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
      Button source = (Button)ae.getSource();
      if (source.getLabel() == "  Play in Loop  "){
         audioClip.play();
      }  
      else if(source.getLabel() == "  Stop  "){
         audioClip.stop();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: and what is the exception on java console ?

Comment: There is no exception. It just does not play the music, as if it cannot located the file, but it's there.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by createding a Music folder and placed the music file in there, and referencing as "Music/spacemusic.au" See this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UaNf53WflLI

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare strings in this way

```
if (source.getLabel() == "  Play in Loop  "){
```

you should use .equals

```
if (source.getLabel().equals("  Play in Loop  ")){
```

Anyway, use a boolean variable to represent if the music is playing or not

Comment: Or check source == play and source == stop

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion. But that did not fix the issue.

Comment: Still not plays? Are you sure texts are equals? Can you add debug messages inside actionPerfomed where you print .getLabel() ?

Comment: I put a debug message in actionPerfomed and it is printing. However, I still do not hear any music from the program.

Comment: Did you add a debug message before audioClip.play() and audioClip.stop()?

Answer (score 0):

> Print the value of **getCodeBase()** and now you can figure it out where is the problem.
>
> Is it pointing to a correct location or not, if yes then is spacemusic.au file present there?

Replace you `actionPerformed` method (use equals in place of == or use == for object reference itself)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    Button source = (Button) ae.getSource();
    if (source == play) {
        audioClip.play();
    } else if (source == stop) {
        audioClip.stop();
    }
}
```